# Codeigniter selecting data with multiple id's

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is an example of my code and an explanation what I am trying to do.

At the beginning of the code I am selecting three variables in my database. I then compare them to a function that determines the distance, if the distance is within the given distance then I have the id of that record. This will result in multiple id's. Could be five or none, depends on the variables given.

What I need to know is once I have determined that id I need to use I need to put into either a variable or something else that is manageable. Basically I need to take the list and query the database again to get the list of details from the database. The list will return objects that will later be past to `json_encode` for processing.

What I need to know is what is the best way to put each id into a variable and pass it to a database query and get the results I need.

I've tried using `$dbStations->where('_id', '34,33,45')` but it only returns the first value. I need something like `WHERE _id = 34 AND 33 AND 45` if possible.

I am using Codeigniter for my framework and I have went over the documentation and I have not found a solution.

EDIT: Now that I have the the data selected from the database I need to get the distance to be displayed at the end of each record retrieved.

```
Example of json: {"details":[{"country":"United States","_id":"3892","lat":"39.954559","lng":"-82.837608","admin_level_1":"Ohio","locale":"Columbus"}]}
```

This is what it needs to be, keep in mind that distance is not in the database, it is calculated on the fly.

```
Example of json: {"details":[{"country":"United States","_id":"3892","lat":"39.954559","lng":"-82.837608","admin_level_1":"Ohio","locale":"Columbus", "distance": "1.2 Mi"}]}
```

Any ideas on how to get ths distance that is caculcated to be appended to the end of each result?

```
        $dbStations->select('lat');
        $dbStations->select('lng');
        $dbStations->select('_id');
        $stations = $dbStations->get('stDetails');
        foreach ($stations->result() as $station) {
            $lat2 = $station->lat;
            $lng2 = $station->lng;
            $stId = $station->_id;
            $distance = $this->distance->gpsdistance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, "M");
                if ($distance <= $rad) {
                //at this point the code has determined that this id is within
                //the preferred distance.
                $stationArr[] = $stId;
            }
        }
            $dbStations->select('country, _id, lat, lng, admin_level_1, locale');
            $dbStations->where_in('_id', $stationArr);
            $stations = $dbStations->get('stationDetails');
        echo json_encode(array('stations' => $stations->result()));
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using `where_in()`

```
$ids = array(33, 34, 45);
$dbStations->where_in('id', $ids);
// Produces: WHERE id IN (33, 34, 45)
```

This will return records that have the ID of 33, 34, 45

Comment: Worked great, I was trying this earlier but just wasn't working out. Thanks a lot.