# CI, How to get data call by multiple id's from database?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want to fetch data from a database with multiple id's in codeigniter.

Instead of one id, I want to use multiple id's.

```
$q = $this->db->select('*')->from('data')->where('FILTER',$a)->get();
return $q->result();
```

Not actually any errors.

Comment: No idea what `FILTER` is, and I don't see any `id`s in your query, but is this what you're after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7605907/6089612 ? The first hit when searching for your title keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
q = $this->db->select('*')->from('data')->where_in('FILTER',$a)->get();
return $q->result();
```